# How to compile a single module inside it in a multi-module maven project?

Tags: java, maven

This is how the project may looks like:

- moduleA

  -- pom.xml
- moduleB

  -- pom.xml
- pom.xml

moduleA has a dependency on moduleB. I have set `<modules>` in the parent pom.xml and other configurations in the child pom.xmls. And I can run `mvn package` in the parent dir, but every time I run `mvn package` in the directory of moduleA it fails.

I know that running `mvn package -pl moduleA` in the parent directory can fix the problem. Since Apache Flume allows me to compile any single module in its own directory, why can't my project?

Comment: When you say it fails, I am taking a guess it is providing an error. Can you please include your `<modules>` section of each POM and also the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Ascalonian Here is what the error message looks like: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project moduleA: Could not resolve dependencies for project ...: Failed to collect dependencies for [...]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.myorg.app.:moduleB:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find org.myorg.app:app-parent:pom:1.0.0 in ... was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of launching goal "package", launch goal "install" on the root pom (or just moduleB). This will place moduleB in the local repository (~/.m2/repository) and Maven will be able to fetch it when it compiles only moduleA. Then you'll be able to compile only moduleA.

Comment: Yes that works. But what if `mvn install` fails due to some other module in the project which moduleA has no dependency on failing to compile? Is there any way to package moduleA under this condition?

Comment: Hi, moduleA can be compiled by Maven if, and only if all its dependencies are available, either in the current build context, in the local repository, or in a remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue: **maven session does not declare a top level project**

when I'm trying to run one module through command line like :- `mvn clean install -pl moduleA` where it was looking for parent module, So I've tried this & it worked with :- `mvn clean install -pl .,moduleA` in your case you can try this assuming dependency is already build & available in maven repo, else `mvn clean install -pl .,moduleA --also-make` should work. This will build only one specific project in multi-module maven project & as we've specified "." it would build parent pom which resolved the issue.